# Read & write an attribute, with default value and validation

Tags: ruby

I am building a class to represent an auto-generated player character. The character has a gender, with the acceptable values being `:male` and `:female`. I need to have an attribute reader and writer to allow access and customization, but also a "default" value in case a value has not been selected yet and the user does not want to select one. I have the following code:

```
class Character
    attr :gender

    def gender= g
        g = nil unless g == :male or g == :female
        @gender = g || [:male, :female].sample
    end

    def gender
        @gender ||= gender=(nil)
    end
end
```

The idea is to always go through the setter to make sure the value is valid, and makes code easier to maintain in case I decide to add new values to the gender list down the road. The problem I'm facing is that a) the validation line has redundant values with the setting line below it (in the gender= method) and b) invoking the writer method from the reader method looks really weird with the "nil" passing. Any thoughts how to make this more elegant?

Comment: If you absolutely must have a randomly selected "default" gender, set that in the initializer, not in the setter, and simply reject invalid values in the setter.  That way you always have a valid gender, so you never need extra logic in the getter, and your setter just needs to validate that the new input isn't something other than :male or :female.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a setter in the getter if you set a valid value in the constructor. In the future, if you are adding a new gender, you can update the existing characters as a one-off thing. This keeps your code cleaner.

```
class Character
    attr :gender

    def initialize
       @gender = valid_genders.sample
    end

    def gender= g
       @gender = g if valid_genders.include? g
    end

    private

    def valid_genders
      [:male, :female]
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is *really* naive, and maybe overkill. If you're really serious about doing this in a clean and fashionable way, and plan on having more than just a gender attribute, you may want to invest in something like...

```
module CoolAttributes

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def attribute(name, type, options = {})
      get(name, type, options)
      set(name, type, options)
    end

    def get(name, type, options)
      define_method(name) do
        instance_variable_get(:"@#{name}") || if options[:default].is_a?(Proc)
                                                options[:default].call
                                              else
                                                options[:default]
                                              end
      end
    end

    def set(name, type, options)
      define_method("#{name}=") do |value|
        instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", self.class.cast_to(type, value))
      end
    end

    def cast_to(type, value)
      if type == :boolean
        if ['false', 0, '0', false].include?(value)
          false
        else
          true
        end
      elsif type == :symbol
        value.to_s.to_sym
      end
    end
  end
end

class Character
  include CoolAttributes

  attribute :gender, :symbol, :default => :male
end

c = Character.new
puts c.gender # male 
c.gender = 'male'
puts c.gender.class # Symbol
```

This is pretty much what `ActiveModel::Attributes` is.

Edit: I ended up making a gem out of this. https://github.com/joshmn/attributary

Answer (score 0):

My version, where you can also initialize at will:

```
class Character
    attr :gender

    def initialize(g = nil)
      valid? g ? @gender = g : @gender = random_gender
    end

    def gender=(g)
      @gender = g if valid? g
    end

    def self.list_genders
      new.genders.each_with_index { |gender, idx| puts "#{idx+1} - #{gender}" }
    end

    def valid?(g)
      g && genders.include?(g)
    end

    def genders
      [:male, :female]
    end

    def random_gender
      genders.sample
    end
end


Character.list_genders
character = Character.new
p character.gender
character = Character.new(:male)
p character.gender
character.gender = :female
character.gender = :none
p character.gender
```